# Getting the address of the end of a buffer instead of its beginning

Tags: c, assembly, buffer, x86-64

I have the following C code:

```
int hey(char *param_1)

{
  char buf[256];
  
  strcpy(buf,param_1);
  printf("Hey ! %s\n",buf);
  return 0;
}
```

This function is called at a time from main. The assembly for  this function is:

```
   0x0000555555555189 <+0>: endbr64 
   0x000055555555518d <+4>: push   rbp
   0x000055555555518e <+5>: mov    rbp,rsp
   0x0000555555555191 <+8>: sub    rsp,0x110
   0x0000555555555198 <+15>:    mov    QWORD PTR [rbp-0x108],rdi
   0x000055555555519f <+22>:    mov    rdx,QWORD PTR [rbp-0x108]
   0x00005555555551a6 <+29>:    lea    rax,[rbp-0x100]
=> 0x00005555555551ad <+36>:    mov    rsi,rdx
   0x00005555555551b0 <+39>:    mov    rdi,rax
   0x00005555555551b3 <+42>:    call   0x555555555070 <strcpy@plt>
   0x00005555555551b8 <+47>:    lea    rax,[rbp-0x100]
   0x00005555555551bf <+54>:    mov    rsi,rax
   0x00005555555551c2 <+57>:    lea    rdi,[rip+0xe3b]        # 0x555555556004
   0x00005555555551c9 <+64>:    mov    eax,0x0
   0x00005555555551ce <+69>:    call   0x555555555090 <printf@plt>
   0x00005555555551d3 <+74>:    mov    eax,0x0
   0x00005555555551d8 <+79>:    leave  
   0x00005555555551d9 <+80>:    ret
```

As you can see I have put a breakpoint using gdb. When I check the content of my registers I see that:

```
rax            0x7fffffffdc80
rbp            0x7fffffffdd80
```

So in my mind, the address of my buffer is `0x7fffffffdc80 (=0x7fffffffdd80-0x100)`.

However when printing the content of the stack with: x/4x I noticed that `0x7fffffffdc80` is actually not the address of my buffer but the address of its end. The real address of my buffer is `0x7fffffffdc80 - 0x100 = 0x7fffffffdb80`.
I came to this conclusion because I am filling my buffer with NOP, a shellcode and many 'A'.

```
(gdb) x/40x 0x7fffffffdb80
0x7fffffffdb80: 0x90909090  0x90909090  0x90909090  0x90909090
0x7fffffffdb90: 0xbb48c031  0x91969dd1  0xff978cd0  0x53dbf748
0x7fffffffdba0: 0x52995f54  0xb05e5457  0x41050f3b  0x41414141
0x7fffffffdbb0: 0x41414141  0x41414141  0x41414141  0x41414141
0x7fffffffdbc0: 0x41414141  0x41414141  0x41414141  0x41414141
0x7fffffffdbd0: 0x41414141  0x41414141  0x41414141  0x41414141
0x7fffffffdbe0: 0x41414141  0x41414141  0x41414141  0x41414141
0x7fffffffdbf0: 0x41414141  0x41414141  0x41414141  0x41414141
0x7fffffffdc00: 0x41414141  0x41414141  0x41414141  0x41414141
0x7fffffffdc10: 0x41414141  0x41414141  0x41414141  0x41414141
```

I do not understand why ? Normally with `lea    rax,[rbp-0x100]` I am passing the address of the beginning of my buffer to rax to prepare for `strcpy` ...

Comment: *"However when printing the content of the stack with: x/4x I noticed that 0x7fffffffdc80 is actually not the address of my buffer but the address of its end"* - how did you come to this conclusion? It's either you or the computer that is wrong... and computers are rarely wrong :')

Comment: I know T_T and it is driving me crazy. I edited the question to answer your comment,

Comment: The stack grows downward on all the modern machine architectures of which I am aware.

Comment: Yes but isn't it weird that we are passing the end of a buffer as the argument of strcpy ? I just can't see the picture clearly ...

Comment: What is at the expected place, `dc80`? Just because the same stuff is also somewhere else, doesn't mean it is the one you should be looking at. Could be leftover garbage. Also are you dumping it **before** the `strcpy`?

Comment: At the expected ```dc80``` I should found my 16 NOP (\x90) but they are not. They are 256 bytes before ```dc80```. And I am showing the stack after the strcpy and reading rbp before the strcpy.

Comment: `buf` is declared without an initializer, and the `strcpy` call has not yet been executed at the point where you appear to have set your breakpoint.  Therefore, at that point, you cannot identify the storage for `buf` by its contents.

Comment: You can verify your assumptions by simply adding a `printf("buf is at %p\n", buf);` to your code

Comment: Post [mcve] so we can try. Also what is `rsi`/`rdx` (ie. the source argument)?

Comment: I did the x/4x after strcpy ... And I am sure I can identify buf by its content because the param of ```hey``` is just a user input. And my input was 16 NOPs + a shellcode + many A ...

Comment: This is for a simple exploit exercise. I do not have the source code (except the one from Ghidra) How can I provide you with the binary file ?

Comment: It is like GDB is altering rbp at some point by 0x100 ...

Comment: Ah I got it but it is super weird. If my arg for hey is "AAAA" then rbp is ```0x7fffffffdd80```. If my arg for hey is "A"*300 then rbp is  ```0x7fffffffdc80``` ... Does someone know how or why ?

Comment: @Rudeus, a difference in %rbp would imply that a function in the call chain prior to the one you are looking at is using a different amount of stack.  If you observe such differences at the same point in different runs of the same program, then my first guess would be that there is a VLA involved.

Comment: That is weird because Ghidra is not detecting the VLA but only the ```buf[256]```

Comment: I'm not very familiar with Ghidra, so I can't say whether it's reasonable to expect it to recognize VLAs.  However, a bit of web searching indicates that it has some trouble with flexible array members, which are similar in some regards.  Reverse engineering tools are imperfect, and I expect VLAs to be pretty tricky to reverse engineer accurately in general.  Also, to be clear: it would be a VLA in a different function, earlier in the call chain, not in `hey()`.

Comment: Do you pass that as a command line argument? Those live further up on the stack and hence cause different layout depending on their size.

Answer (score 2):

> As you can see I have put a breakpoint using gdb. When I check the
> content of my registers I see that:
>
> ```
> rax            0x7fffffffdc80
> rbp            0x7fffffffdd80
> ```
>
> So in my mind, the address of my buffer is `0x7fffffffdc80 (=0x7fffffffdd80-0x100)`.

Given that `%rax` is about to be loaded into `%rdi` for use as the first argument to `strcpy()`, that seems to be the correct analysis.

> However when printing the content of the stack with: x/4x I noticed
> that [...] The real address of my buffer is [different]. I came to this conclusion because I [found my input data in a different location]

If you examine memory while the program is stopped at the breakpoint you show then you cannot identify the storage for `buf` by its contents, because `buf` is declared without an initializer, and the breakpoint is *before* the `strcpy()` call.  The contents of `buf` are indeterminate from the C language perspective, and if you examine its memory with a debugger then there is no particular reason to expect any specific contents.

That you happen to see data you recognize nearby in stack memory is irrelevant, especially if, as appears to be the case, that memory is below `%rsp`.  You are presumably looking at garbage left behind on the stack by execution of some previous function.

If you are unconvinced then there are any number of ways to verify, such as

- initialize `buf` in its declaration, and use that to recognize its location.  For example,

  ```
      char buf[256] = { 0xb, 0xf /*, the rest will be 0 */ };
  ```
- store the address of `buf` in a pointer, and inspect that

  ```
      char *bufp = buf;
  ```
- print the address of `buf`

  ```
      printf("%p\n", buf);
  ```

  (Technically, the relationship of the output to the machine address is not specified, but in practice, you are likely to get a hex dump of the address's numeric value).